# Using the same class as both Code First Entity Model and WCF Data Contract

Tags: wcf, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I am using the following DataContract for transferring over the WCF Service:

```
[DataContract]
public class User
{
    [DataMember]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

When the Service Operation transfers this object, the connection to the client is forcibly closed.

But, when I remove the `StringLength` attribute from the above contract, it works. This `StringLength` attribute is present because this same class is acting as an entity class (POCO class) for the Entity Framework Code First Model.

How can I resolve this other than defining the string length restriction in the `Fluent API`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data Annotation attributes are not firing in WCF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430185/data-annotation-attributes-are-not-firing-in-wcf)

Answer (score 0):

please follow these links maybe fix your problem:

[wcfdataannotations](https://wcfdataannotations.codeplex.com/)

[stackoverflow.com/questions/20430185/data-annotation-attributes-are-not-firing-in-wcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430185/data-annotation-attributes-are-not-firing-in-wcf)

Comment: Useful links, but please vote to close as duplicate in stead of posting a link-only answer.