# Empty property not causing a validation failure despite StringLength attribute

Tags: c#, web-services, validation, datacontractserializer

I have a class that is called MyMethodQuery that contains a property of entry of my web method

```
[DataContract()]
public class MyMethodQuery
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 10)]
    public string Id{ get; set; }
}
```

My Web Method :

```
public string MyMethod(MyMethodQuery MyMethodQuery)
{
   return "it's ok !";
}
```

I want to throw an exception if I leave the empty property. But it doesn't work in spite of the attribute `StringLength`.

I test my method with SoapUI.

Answer (score 0):

These attributes are not supposed to work in this context "out of the box". [Validator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator(VS.100).aspx) class is the entry point to the world of validation, and you will have to invoke it manually.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20444456/60188) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
[DataContract()]
public class MyMethodQuery: IValidatableObject
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    [StringLength(500, MinimumLength = 5)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
         if (Id.Length < 1)
         {
             yield return new ValidationResult("error");
         }
    }
}
```

But i have not error return if `Id` is empty