# WCF annotations from Devtrends not working

Tags: c#, wcf, data-annotations

I'm trying to use the Data annotations in the WCF Data contract to validate the data members. Unfortunately, this link is not working.

http://schemas.devtrends.co.uk/example/data.

Is there any other way of validating the data members other than manually writing code to validate the length, check whether it is null or not etc.

Note : 
One of the option to use the Data annotations for validating fields in the service is to use the WCFDataannotations from Devtrends - some of the links contains the information about to use WCF Data annotations from Devtrends. But this is a problem where the WCFDataannotations from Devtrends  is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data Annotation attributes are not firing in WCF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430185/data-annotation-attributes-are-not-firing-in-wcf)

Comment: @RicardoPontual This question is different from the one which you have mentioned. In the link which you have mentioned - one of the answer was to use WCFDataannotations from Devtrends. But this is a problem where the WCFDataannotations from Devtrends (as mentioned in the title) is not working. So trying to find alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

The [WCF Data Annotations](https://wcfdataannotations.codeplex.com/) project seems to be the only one of this kind. And its title page contains pretty good howto of what has to be done.

Did you do everything that is mentioned there? Typical error is to forget implement `IValidatableObject`.